# SetForegroundWindow not working, how to check Class/Caption names

Tags: c#, winforms, bringtofront

I have a program which runs in the background, and when something happens a message box appears, I want to have it so clicking yes will switch to a specified program.

I just can't find what ClassName and CaptionName work with it, I need it to work with the game World of Warcraft.

The Window Title is "Wold of Warcraft" on Task manager its called "World of Warcraft Retail", when I inspect its' properties it says "Wow-64" Properties, on properties it says product name is "World of Warcraft" so I've tried every combination of these and nothing works. The code works if I put:
                BringToFront("Notepad", "Untitled - Notepad");

So it works, I just don't know what I need for it to apply to WoW.

My code is:

```
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 SetForegroundWindow(int hWnd);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    private void BringToFront(string className, string CaptionName)
    {
        SetForegroundWindow(FindWindow(className, CaptionName));
    }

    private void Alert()
    {        
        string title = "WoW Queue Alert: Message";
        string message = "The Queue is ready to accept!";
        MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
        DialogResult result;

        result = MessageBox.Show(new Form() { TopMost = true }, message, title, buttons, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
        {
        BringToFront("World of Warcraft Retail", "World of Warcraft");
        } 
    }
```

I really don't see anything special about WoW, and going by how the notepad example works the correct code should be:

```
            BringToFront("World of Warcraft Retail", "World of Warcraft");
```

Being a fullscreen program should affect it, and I can't see there being anyway Blizzard has implemented something to stop this function.

Edit:  I just set the ClassName to null and works, as caption name is just the window title. No idea what the ClassName is I tried everything I could find.

Comment: What is `FindWindow` returning?

Comment: Error checking is *not* optional when you pinvoke winapi functions.  You don't have the friendly .NET exceptions to keep you out of trouble anymore, you have to raise them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some window inspection tool to inspect the window of World of Warcraft to get its `Class Name` and `Window Name`. A suggestion would be [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460756.aspx) if you installed Visual Studio (it comes along with it). It can help you detect the window's `Class Name` and `Window Name`, and Windows Messages sent to that window easily.

For example, the picture below shows all windows in current environment. Highlighted entry is a PowerPoint instance, which has `Caption` = "Microsoft PowerPoint" and `ClassName` = "PPTFrameClass".

[image: spy++]

Another approach will be writing a "always-inactivate" winform and call `GetForegroundWindow` from that form to get the window handle of the window you want.

To create an "always-inactivate" winform, simply override its `CreateParams` property:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams p = base.CreateParams;

        p.ExStyle |= 0x8000000; // WS_EX_NOACTIVATE - requires Win 2000 or higher

        return p;
    }
}
```

By overriding this, the form won't get focus **even on a mouse click**. Therefore, you could create a button to trigger `GetForegroundWindow()`. Signature of the function in C# looks like below:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
```

which returns the window handle of current fore ground window.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Express which doesn't appear to have spy++ I downloaded this: http://web.archive.org/web/20090916053057/http://www.windows-spy.com/ which is meant to do all Spy++ does but as an external program, and I can't see anything from the information displayed that is the Class/Caption Names.

Comment: I edited my post to include a screen shot of spy++, did you see something like this?

Comment: I explored the link you gave, and seems the application gives the Class-Caption pair in "Windows list". Under window list, every entry reads as: Handle-ClassName-CaptionName